# How to post large wall post with vkapi?

Tags: php, http, web, http-post, vk

I want to post large announcement to my wall in `vk.com`. Through use of `vkapi` method `wall.post` I couldn't do this because of large message size. Is there any technique to approach my aim?

Comment: What is text-size I wonder? POST-request to wall.post-method is only way you can post any messages on walls in vk.com, and POST has more ability except GET, so you should use it if you're not

Comment: Hreno, thanks. It's about 700 bytes. Maybe there are other methods, I'll check it out. And yes, I use POST method exactly.

Comment: Something wrong with your request, because GET-limit is nearly 14 Kb of data, so the problem is not in post-data size